# SonarQube Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, docker, sonarqube

I'm trying to run Sonarqube on Docker on Windows and I'm getting this error **Could not reserve enough space for object heap**

`2017.11.09 13:59:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
2017.11.09 13:59:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.JavaProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[web]: C:\ojdkbuild\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube\temp -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\sonarqube\lib\jdbc\mysql\mysql-connector-java-5.1.42.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube\temp\sq-process2378470284594445664properties
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
2017.11.09 13:59:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.11.09 13:59:50 INFO  es[][o.s.p.StopWatcher] Stopping process`

To run the Sonarqube, my command looks like,

`java -jar lib/sonar-application-%SONARQUBE_VERSION%.jar -Dsonar.log.console=true -Dsonar.jdbc.username="%SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME%" -Dsonar.jdbc.password="%SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD%" -Dsonar.jdbc.url="%SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL%" -Dsonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts="%SONARQUBE_WEB_JVM_OPTS% -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom" -Dsonar.verbose=true`

I have tried setting the environment variable `JAVA_OPTS '-Xmx3062m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m'` as well but no difference in the output

**UPDATE:**
1. Updated Sonar parameters to include `-Dsonar.web.javaOpts="-Xmx1g -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError"`
2. Memory allocated to container `--memory 3g`

But still getting same error

Please suggest if I should be changing anything to make this work

Comment: How much memory is allocated to docker ?

Comment: What does `free -m` tell you (from inside the docker)?

Comment: 3 sub-processes are created under the hood by the bootstrap process "java -jar lib/...jar". Increasing its memory size is useless. You should check the *.javaOpts properties described in sonar.properties.

Comment: I updated the `javaOpts` to `-Xmx1g -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` but I'm still getting this error. I can execute `free -m` as the container just stops